# ESP8266 GET request not working

Tags: http, arduino-uno, esp8266

I am trying to send data from an Arduino Uno using ESP8266 to Firebase via PHP. The connection between the Firebase DB and PHP seems to be fine since I can manually send data to it through my browser. However, I am not able to send data from the Arduino to PHP.

Here is the Arduino code:

```cpp
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

String ssid ="xxxx";
String password="xxxx";

String server = "firstfirebase.000webhostapp.com"; // www.example.com
String uri = "/firebaseTest.php";// our example is /esppost.php

SoftwareSerial esp(2, 3);// RX, TX

void setup() {
  esp.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  reset();
  connectWifi();
}

void reset() {
  esp.println("AT+RST");
  delay(1000);
  if(esp.find("OK"))
    Serial.println("Module Reset");
}

void connectWifi() {
  String cmd = "AT+CWJAP=\"" +ssid+"\",\"" + password + "\"";
  esp.println(cmd);
  delay(4000);
  if(esp.find("OK")) {
    Serial.println("Connected!");
  } else {
    connectWifi();
    Serial.println("Cannot connect to wifi");
  }
}

void loop() {
  httppost();
  delay(1000);
}

void httppost () {
  esp.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"firstfirebase.000webhostapp.com\",80");//start a TCP connection.
  if( esp.find("OK")) {
    Serial.println("TCP connection ready");
  }
  delay(1000);
  String getRequest = "GET firebaseTest.php?arduino_data=56.00 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: firstfirebase.000webhostapp.com\r\n\r\n";
  String sendCmd = "AT+CIPSEND";//determine the number of caracters to be sent.
  esp.print(sendCmd);
  esp.println(getRequest.length() );
  delay(500);
  if(esp.find(">")) {
    Serial.println("Sending..");
    esp.print(getRequest+"\r\n\r\n");
    delay(500);
    esp.println("AT+CIPSTATUS");
    if( esp.find("SEND OK")) {
      Serial.println("Packet sent");
      while (esp.available()) {
        String tmpResp = esp.readString();
        Serial.println(tmpResp);
      }
      // close the connection
      esp.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the serial monitor:

[image]

Comment: What's the point of the `server` and `uri` variables, if you are not using them?

Comment: I didnt use them because I thought I didnt concatenate the string properly. But that doesnt answer my question

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `/` in front of your path.

It should be:

```cpp
 String getRequest = "GET /firebaseTest.php?arduino_data=56.00 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: firstfirebase.000webhostapp.com\r\n\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The user Agent it is very important:

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","somedomain.it",80

AT+CIPSEND=EXACT NUMBER OF GET REQ

GET /Arduino/ciao.php HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: 192.168.0.111\r\n
User-Agent: wget/1.12\r\n\r\n
```